# How to add an element into a multiMap?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm using a multimap to sort my words by length. The integer is the word's length.
I was wondering how I can add words to the List.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mmap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

Say I have two words, "bob" and "can"
they are both 3 letters. Could someone give me a little pointer on how I would do this?

Comment: Note that a map of lists isn't really a multimap. You could instead use a Guava `Multimap`, which would handle inserting multiple elements with the same key automatically.

Comment: Given the word length is going be min 0 max something small like <100 I would use a List<List<String>> as its more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

With [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) you can create or retrieve the inner collection for a key, and then add to it, in one tidy line:

```
mmap.computeIfAbsent(word.length(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(word);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If(mmap.containsKey(word.length())){
  mmap.get(word.length()).add(word);
}else{
  List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>;
  list.add(word);
  mmap.put(word.length(), list)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your example cleared things up with my confusion about get/put. I was wondering how I would access the words too. If I wanted to print the words that are a certain length, how would I go about with this?

Comment: Given that the key is the number of characters, `mmap.get(num)` would get you the `List<String>` with the words.

Comment: As @frozenkoi said `mmap.get(num)` return list of words in num length. for example `mmap.get(3)` gives words list length is 3. `print(mmap.get(num))` should do, or you can iterate over list.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list of set.

```
private final List<Set<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();


public void add(String word) {
    while(list.size() <= word.length()) list.add(new HashSet<>());
    list.get(word.length()).add(word);
 }
```